# SQL Query WHERE is not

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hi I am looking to carry out a query were i have 3 different countries specified and id like to make a where statement find all attributes where the country is no = United Kingdom. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: share your schema, sample data and whatever code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  country <> 'United Kingdom'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM country 
WHERE name NOT IN('United Kingdom')
```

Comment: There's no reason to use a list in the case of filtering out a single value.

Comment: That is true. However expending on user original question to weed out more than one value. But you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT *
FROm table
WHERE country <> 'United Kingdom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [inequality operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal), `<>`?

```
SELECT *
FROM tblAttributes
WHERE Country <> 'United Kingdom'
```